# How to save the dictionary that have tuple keys

Tags: python, dictionary, save, tuples

I would like to save the dictionary having tuple on keys.

I tried pickle, ujson, json to save the dictionary. All of them did not work.

The dictionary has:

```
dictionary = {(-30, -29, -72, -71): [[-29.99867621124457, -71.75349423197208, 220], [-29.996964568219873, -71.7521560207641, 220], [-29.99696437241995, -71.7507330056961, 220], [-29.99761665426199, -71.75016101067708, 220]]}
```

I tried:

```
with open('depth_echo.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(ujson.dumps(dictionary)

import json
a, b, c = "abc"
data = {(1,2,3):(a,b,c), (2,6,3):(6,3,2)}
on_disk = json.dumps(data.items())
```

Comment: is `ujson` an external library?

Comment: I have added an answer to your question. I can bet you are not using properly `ujson` beause I just tried it, and it works well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

write the dictionary as string

```
 with open(r'test.txt','w+') as f:
     f.write(str(dictionary))
```

read using `eval`

```
dic = ''
with open(r'test.txt','r') as f:
         for i in f.readlines():
            dic=i #string
dic = eval(dic) # this is orignal dict with instace dict
```

Comment: Thanks. Saving worked. But when I read using eval, an error code occurred (I think nan values are in key's element: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grid_map.py", line 101, in <module>
    dic = eval(dic) # this is orignal dict with instace dict
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined

Comment: @DonggyunKim that is some issue with your dictionary, just in that text use `dic.replace('nan','"nan"')` then use nan ,it will work

Comment: Is this a right code? But still same error with this code. dic = ''
with open(r'depth_echo.txt','r') as f:
         for i in f.readlines():
            dic=i 
dic.replace('nan', '"nan"')
dic = eval(dic)

Comment: This is one example having nan in element. [-10.88394467633472, -78.22531460310272, nan]

Comment: dic.replace('nan',0)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`ujson`](https://pypi.org/project/ujson/), this is appropriate to address what you want. I just tried it and it works properly. If you use `json` you will get the following error:

> TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not tuple

```
import ujson

d = {(-30, -29, -72, -71): [[-29.99867621124457, -71.75349423197208, 220], [-29.996964568219873, -71.7521560207641, 220], [-29.99696437241995, -71.7507330056961, 220], [-29.99761665426199, -71.75016101067708, 220]]}

# save dictionary
with open('depth_echo.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(ujson.dumps(d))
```

Make sure you installed `ujson` since it is not part of the Python standard library:

```
pip install ujson
```

Comment: I tried with that code. Actually, the dictionary has more keys and element. And an error occurred with error code: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grid_map.py", line 97, in <module>
    file.write(ujson.dumps(diction))
OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached

Comment: @DonggyunKim, this is weird, I run the code exactly with the example you provided, and it worked properly, and I have the following content in the file: `{"(1, 2, 3)":["a","b","c"],"(2, 6, 3)":[6,3,2]}%`